# In Protractor, how to use import of a module?

Tags: module, protractor

I use Protractor for testing a non-angular web site. I am able to use Protractor to make simple things like clicking and waiting on an element, and reading content of an element (text for example inside a span, etc). I want however to be able to do something like importing a module, like from angular. IUs this possible:

```
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
```

How would I do this?

Comment: are you using javascript or typescript?

Comment: I prefer to use typescript, but anything would be good.

Comment: I want to use that syntax import {} but it looks to me like it is not possible with Protractor.

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov do you know how would I use typescript in Protractor? I only see how to use it with javascript, since it uses the old angular.js syntax to include modules etc.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic try here https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.4.1/exampleTypescript

Comment: no, I work with js. Basically all advanced functionality comes from node.js so you may wanna go through their documentation. I'll share some of my experience of importing things in a bit

Answer (score 0):

So first, you wanna install your packages with `npm`, I'm sure you already know how to do this. NPM is a node package manager, which means everything is managed by node, that's why you'll depend on node.js functionality, and it's nice to go through documentation

`Protractor` is a package itself and as everything else it may be installed locally (to your working direction), or globally (to your system). When you install anything locally it goes to `node_modules` folder. IMPORTANT, `node_modules` is a default folder where node looks for packages. So if you use `let module = require(path)`, your path can be an actual path (relative: `./../../module`, or absolute: `/Users/user/Documents/module`), it can also be just a name of the package `let module = require("xlsx")`. In this case node will look for `xlsx` package inside the closest `node_modules` folder.

Closest means that your project may have multiple `node_modules`. Consider this folder structure

```
project-+-folder1
        |
        +-folder2
        |
        +-node_modules
        |
        +-folder3-+-node_modules
                  |
                  +-another-folder-+
                                   |
                                   +-spec.js
```

If you say `let module = require("xlsx")` in your `spec.js`, then node will look for `xlsx` package inside your `node_modules` UNDER `folder3`, then if not found it will move one directory up and check inside `node_modules` UNDER `project` folder etc. If nothing found, it'll try to look for specified package globally (outside of your project). That is done to reduce the hassle with relative paths (`./../../..`).

Now, when you have basics of import theory in node using javascript, here is the answer to your question:

once you install the package, you may import it using [require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) method